# How to setup plain text env vars in Expo build?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on an expo project and trying to link [environment variables for build profiles](https://docs.expo.dev/build/eas-json/#environment-variables). I was trying to achieve that using `eas.json` but I cannot get it to work.

I have two build profiles - development and production:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.3.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "https://staging-api.example.com",
        "STRIPE_ENV": "test"
      },
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "https://api.example.com",
        "STRIPE_ENV": "production"
      },
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "autoIncrement": true
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Build command:

```
eas build --profile development --platform ios
```

Based on their [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/), I sohuld be able to use `process.env.API_URL` but it's undefined.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Which expo version are you using?

Comment: There might be a typo ```proces.env.API_URL```-> ```process.env.API_URL```

Comment: Fixed the typo. It was correct on the code.  I'm using `"expo": "~47.0.8",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting those values in eas.json is only ensuring that those envs will be set during the build process on EAS. To pass them to the application code you need to pass those values to the extra field in `app.config.js`.

`process.env.API_URL` will be defined when evaluating `app.config.js`, but in your application code, you need to access those values via `expo-constants` package.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out. Is there a way to use `autoIncrement: true` with `app.config.js`?

Comment: yes, but you will need to use managed versioning where current version is stored on expo servers and injected when building. https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/app-versions/

Comment: Here is an description how you can achieve that you can use one config for eas and local builds https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#can-i-share-environment-variables-defined-in-easjson-with-expo-start-and-eas-update